# Remove specified Children element of a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, children

I need to remove at runtime a specified element of a Grid (grid1). This is the code where i add the elements.

```
 examControls.Add(excontrol);  // add the element on the ArrayList
 excontrol.Margin = new Thickness(x, y + margin, 0, 0);
 grid1.Children.Add(excontrol);
```

How can i remove at runtime a specified "excontrol" element (added at runtime) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to do that in XAML instead. Post a screenshot of what you need and we can give you a right way to implement it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you keep a record of the control you can simply do:

```
grid1.Children.Remove(excontrol);
```

If you don't have a variable that holds the control you wish to remove you'll have to identify it in some way (Tag, Name), then find that control in the grid's children and then call `Remove`.

Comment: does this free up memory space?

Comment: @AricFowler - I would assume so, once `excontrol` falls out of scope and isn't referenced anywhere else.

Answer (score 6):

```
grid1.Children.Remove(excontrol) //edited per your edit -- this is exactly what ChrisF posted though
```

or

```
grid1.Children.RemoveAt(index)
```

Comment: @NicolòCarpignoli No problem. In the future, documentation is your friend. To find the answer to your question, I just googled "c# wpf grid". [This pops up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) as the first result. You'll see `Children` is a [`UIElementCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.aspx) which shows you exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: And now when I google it, this answer pops up. So, ya know...thanks for asking lol